# Apt-get install tomcat7

Tags: ssh, homebrew, virtualbox

I am currently running Mavericks. I have a Drupal7 Virtual Machine running (on VirtualBox). I am trying to install a tomcat7 server onto the VM. I have used the Terminal to SSH and login to my Drupal7 VM but cannot seem to install tomcat7. I am aware that on Windows you use the command: apt-get install tomcat7, however this doesn't work on Mac. 
I have tried to use Homebrew, but it doesn't seem to install on the VM through the terminal command.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system is the virtual machine running?

Comment: It running Debian 64bit - can i be using host-only adapter?

Answer (score 1):

To install [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) on Debian, follow the instructions provided by Digital Ocean: [How To Install and Configure Apache Tomcat on a Debian Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-tomcat-on-a-debian-server).

The two steps are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Installing Tomcat on your virtual machine does not require Mac OS X specific commands. Your installation is taking place within the virtual machine and all the commands should be Debian specific.

Comment: thanks, i will try that late. Can i be using host-only adapter as when i try to use bridged network i get:'error optaining ip address, lease failed, failed to bring up eth0' when assigned an ip address to the vm

Comment: @jake12321 please can you ask this as a separate VirtualBox on Mac question. That way you will attract better, more specific, and hopefully more informed answers.